# GMAIL API Google AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I have made a simple function:

```
function checkVacation () {

Logger.log(Gmail.Users.Settings.getVacation('notmyadress@exampledomain.com'));

}
```

And the error appears: API call to gmail.users.settings.getVacation failed with error: Delegation denied.

When I'm using ".getVacation('me'). It shows correctly. Only when I'm trying to search another people in domain

Comment: What is your role in the Domain? Are you an admin?

Comment: I'm an administrator

Comment: Are you a delegate of the user you are trying to get? You can't just get other people's settings without their permission.

Comment: Can you add in some context to your question? What are you trying to do? Why do you need this setting? Do you need other settings? Because maybe you will need a service account with domain wide delegation of authority to do what you need.

Comment: I need  information  about gmail seetings of all people from our domain like: do they have "enableAutoReply" and the body of this information, and the time from, when to when. After this i will create later a synchronic bot

Comment: I think this may be a roundabout way to get what you need. There exists the "out of office" functionality... https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/7638168?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid#:~:text=Show%20when%20you're%20out,out%2Dof%2Doffice%20dates.  Why isin't that good enough? Service accounts are very powerful, potentially unsecure and should not be used unless necessary.

Comment: i'm really care about it to use GMAil API